# Finding the count of the mode of a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Is there a more elegant/efficient way of doing this?

My current solution is to find the mode:

```
max(set(lst), key=lst.count)
```

Then to find the amount of occurrences of that in the list:

```
lst.count(max(set(lst), key=lst.count))
```

With this solution python has to do a count twice. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to return the count of the mode, as well as the actual mode.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `lst`?

Comment: Use `collections.Counter`, maybe?

Comment: "With this solution python has to do a count twice". No, it has to count n+1 times, where n is the number of unique elements in the list. Use `collections.Counter(lst[1]).most_common(1)` to get the mode and its count.

Comment: Why are you using `lst[1]` for one part then `lst` itself for another? If that's a typo, please [edit] to fix, and please add an example of `lst` while you're there.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is very close to being a good question :) it's just `lst` vs `lst[1]` that's holding it back. It could maybe use a bit of copy-editing too, but I can easily take care of that once it's clarified :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick way to go that uses [`Counter` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from `collections`, a package that doesn't need to be installed.

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [1, 2, 3, 1]
counted_items = Counter(lst)
most_frequent_item, frequency = counted_items.most_common(n=1)[0]

print(most_frequent_item, frequency)  # prints 1 2
```